# Using a while loop to compare to a value in a array

Tags: java, arrays

I need the program to run in a loop until 0 is entered. My code will end with 0 entered but when attempting to run the program with numbers entered it still ends the program. instead of running the numbers entered. The while loop is to keep the program running unless a 0 is entered.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CountCompare {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the integers between 1 and 100 (0 to end, 0 < to exit): ");
        int[] counts = new int[100];
        // Count occurrence of numbers
        count(counts);

        while(counts[0] > 0){
            // Display results
            for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
                if (counts[i] > 0)
                    System.out.println((i + 1) + " occurs " + counts[i] +
                            " time" + (counts[i] > 1 ? "s" : ""));
            }
            System.out.print("Enter the integers between 1 and 100 : ");

            // Count occurrence of numbers
            count(counts);
        }
        System.out.print("\nEnd of run");
    }

    /** Method count reads integers between 1 and 100 
     *   and counts the occurrences of each */
    public static void count(int[] counts){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num; // holds user input
        do {
            num = input.nextInt();
            if (num >= 1 && num <= 100) 
                counts[num - 1]++;
        } while (num != 0);
    }
}

I have posted the entire program.
```

output looks like this

Enter the integers between 1 and 100 (0 to end, <0 to exit): 
23 23 4 5 6 7 8
0
4 occurs 1 time
5 occurs 1 time
6 occurs 1 time
7 occurs 1 time
8 occurs 1 time
23 occurs 2 times

Enter the integers between 1 and 100:

Comment: look to use the `Scanner` class to get input from stdin

Comment: I think you should show us a little more code... like where you are reading in these numbers?

Comment: Where is the input performed?

Comment: what do you expect to be output of this program?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Answer (score 1):

Your program still ends because:

```
int[] counts = new int[100];
```

You have defined the limit of the counts here. This means your loop will run

```
for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)// counts.length=100;
```

So as far as you code suggest you want to end the user input when user input 0. So you might do this:

```
int x=1;
int y;
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    while(x!=0){
    System.out.println("Enter your values");
    y=sc.nextInt();
     if(y==0){
      x=0;
}
else{
System.out.println("You entered "+y);
}
```

Comment: there is a missing "}" at the end of your code, to close the while loop. Other than that, I would add sc.close(); in the else to close the scanner, if your code runs further.

Answer (score 0):

```
int count=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
int myarray[]=new int[count];
for(int tmp=0; tmp<count;)
    myarray[tmp]=++tmp;
while(count != 0){
    for(int inc=1; inc<=count; inc++){
        System.out.println(inc + "times occur");
    }
    System.out.println("Enter 0 to exit");
    count=new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the line

while(counts[0] > 0) {

and try to figure out what is the purpose of this while loop in the main method.